# I need to parse the output of Google Script logger.log

Tags: parsing, logging

I'm writing a small script to pull the user list out of an email group and add certain individuals to a different "master" group. My Log Output of the looks like what you see below. The sis only adding the first name. Does anyone know how to paste the whole list into a gmail group or is there a way to put the output of the Logger.log into a .csv and then loop through it to add each name individually?

Log Output:

> [16-06-20 08:05:31:123 PDT] [name@domain.com, name@domain.com,
>   name@domain.com, name@domain.com, name@domain.com, name@domain.com,
>   name@domain.com, name@domain.com, name@domain.com, name@domain.com,
>   name@domain.com] [16-06-20 08:05:32:205 PDT]

Current code :

```
function getGroupMembers() {
    var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var groupEmail = values.getRange(17, 5).getDisplayValue();
    var userEmail = values.getRange(17, 4).getDisplayValue();
    var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(userEmail);
    var users = group.getUsers();
    for (var u = 0; u < users.length; u++) {
        var member = {
            email : users,
            role : 'MEMBER'
        }
    }
    member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
    Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}
```

Comment: What language do you use ? (Add it in the tags)

Comment: Doing this in Google Script editor, It's ugly I know. Basically I'm pulling a list of users from a sub group and adding the list to the main group, but it's only adding the first name in the list:

Comment: May I see the actual code ?

Comment: function getGroupMembers() {
     var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var groupEmail = values.getRange(17, 5).getDisplayValue();
    var userEmail = values.getRange(17, 4).getDisplayValue();
    var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(userEmail);
    var users = group.getUsers();
    for (var u = 0; u < users.length; u++){
 var member = {
   email: users,
    role: 'MEMBER'
     }
}
member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
   Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}

Comment: sorry about the format issue

Comment: I presume you try to add all `users` in `AdminDirectory.Members` ?

Comment: Yes. "member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail); "

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me if this fits your needs. I put the `insert` in the for loop and set email using `users[u]` instead of `users`. Otherwise, the loop was useless.

By the way, the language used by Google Script is `JavaScript`.

```
function getGroupMembers() {
    var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var groupEmail = values.getRange(17, 5).getDisplayValue();
    var userEmail = values.getRange(17, 4).getDisplayValue();
    var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(userEmail);
    var users = group.getUsers();
    for (var u = 0; u < users.length; u++) {
        var member = {
            email : users[u],
            role : 'MEMBER'
        };
        Logger.log('u=' + u + '---' + users[u]);
        //member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
    }
    Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}
```

Comment: Nope, still only loads the first user in the list

Comment: Can you log `users.length` and tell me the value ?

Comment: [16-06-21 08:11:31:027 EDT] 11.0

Comment: honestly it's been giving me nightmares

Comment: May I see the `AdminDirectory.Members.insert` code ? Because it doesn't seem to be in Google Script.

Comment: All the code I have is posted there. It works, the first user in the list gets added just fine, but the other 10 get skipped.

Comment: Try add `Logger.log('u=' + u + '---' + users[u]); as the first line of the `for` loop and give me back the result.

Comment: u=0---Name@Domain.com           this lists the name of the first user, the only one who gets added to the group.

Comment: And the second entry (u==1) ?

Comment: there's no 2nd entry,

Comment: Euh... you told me that `users.length` == 11. So the `for` loop shall have been executed 11 times. Did you put the log call in the `for` loop ?

Comment: the loop eventually finds all 11 members but the add member command only processes the first one and then quits. I'm so frustrated I'm about to give up and do all this manually every time which would suck

Comment: I just changed the code. I disabled the insert command and put a Log one instead. Can you run it like that and tell me if the log now have more than one entry (like the u==1) ?

Comment: Yes! it lists u=0 through u=10 with appropriate user emails. Still no adds though

Comment: Well this is sure there is no add now because I commented/disabled the insert line. So, for sure, the problem is coming from this insert code. Can you check if you have any other files on your left or a library added in the menu "Resources->Libraries". The AdminDirectory doesn't exist when I create a project with Google Script Editor.

Comment: I've given up. What I'm trying to do is evidently impossible. I copied all the group names to a .csv and ran a group add on each individually. It worked but it was not elegant at all

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't fix it. At least your were able to do.

Comment: Yeah, found a workable solution, not as elegant but workable. Thanks for everything.